# Failed attempts to connect MyODBC Connector to MariaDB. Error 10060 on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to make an ODBC connection from a windows box to a remote Ubuntu server with MyODBC Connector.
BACKGROUND:

- I have configured the /etc/mysql/my.conf (commented out the
  bind-address, and the skip-networking)
- I have port 3306 open, on my ufw firewall.
- I have granted access on the remote MariaDB with: GRANT
  ALL ON user1.* TO 'db1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '(pwd)’' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Wierd responses:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep -i mariadb (returns:)
tcp   0   0 127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      964/mariadbd
```

So, it looks like MariaDB **is** listening on port 3306.

But,

```
$ sudo nmap -sT x.x.x.x -p 3306 (returns:)
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql
```

So it looks like MariaDB is **not** listening to port 3306, hence my 10060 error.

Am I interpreting this correctly?
How can I connect to my remote MariaDB on Ubuntu Server 22.04? I have read all the documentation, and it all seems to come down to these things, which I have done.

Comment: Where is the database server being hosted? If it's on AWS or Azure, you may have a network firewall that is preventing the connection from going through 